# How can I get all the versions of a given file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to obtain all the versions of a given file in my SVN repository. For instance, let's say that the file ThirdPartyAssembly.dll was checked 3 times, is there a command that will get me all the version on my HD (e.g. ThirdPartyAssembly.dll.v1, ThirdPartyAssembly.dll.v2, ThirdPartyAssembly.dll.v3, etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

there is no command out of the box but you can build simple script that uses `log -q` command output.

```
zerkms@honeypot /var/www/cv $ svn log -q index.html
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r17 | zerkms | 2010-04-21 21:47:16 +1100 (Wed, 21 Apr 2010)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r16 | zerkms | 2010-04-21 21:37:03 +1100 (Wed, 21 Apr 2010)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r15 | zerkms | 2010-04-21 21:36:46 +1100 (Wed, 21 Apr 2010)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14 | zerkms | 2010-04-21 21:32:37 +1100 (Wed, 21 Apr 2010)
... etc
```

so you just need to parse first column in your favorite scripting language

after this just do:

```
svn copy http://server/full/path/to/file@14 file.rev.14
```

etc, for each revision and you will get bunch of `file.rev.XX`

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click with mouse on the selected file ThirdPartyAssembly.dll in your working copy on your HD, and a popup menu appears.
2. From the popup menu choose on TortoiseSVN > Show log, and a window appears
3. The window contains the list of ALL the checked in versions of your file
4. RIGHT click mouse on the one that you want, a pop up menu appears.
5. Form the popup menu choose "Save revision to..." and you can save it on your HD wherever you like.

Comment: I have 98 revisions of that file, is there a way to have a batch file doing that?

Comment: Thanks Marco! It's a good solution, but the "Save revision to..." isn't available when I select more than one revision.

Comment: @Martin: "I have 98 revisions..." I didn't know that, you were talking about 3/4 revisions in your question. I don't know then.

Comment: @Marco: I still like your solution! :) I will try to script it, otherwise I might do that one by one... :S

Comment: @Martin: isn't it more simple to script the CLI instead of GUI? :-S

Comment: @zerkms: if it's not a long script could you write it out, I'm interested too. How do I call that script than from normal command Windows' shell? Thanks!

Comment: @Marco: i told about any scripting language that you have on the host system that you use: bash, bat, python, php, perl... i propose to use anything you OP has and anything he know how to program, but basing on CLI out (`svn log -q file`)

Comment: @zerkms: sorry, i'm very ignorant in this subject. But is this command to be called on my local PC or it ha s to be called on the server hosting the repository? I downloaded TortoiseSVN, but I cant' find any svn.exe command on my machine.

Comment: tortoisesvn is exclusively GUI tool. it's sexy, but it's GUI. so you need to download SVN which contains command line tool svn.exe. in my answer i put sample output

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a diff command on each version to get CVS to generate copies of the old files. You could probably even script this if there are a lot of old revisions.

But that said, what exactly are you really trying to do here? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I am exactly trying to do what I said in the question. I need to get all the versions of a file (binary) on my machine. Thanks! :)